# Passport JS and custom async/await function

Tags: javascript, async-await, passport.js

I'm using Passport JS local strategy and would like to add a custom function that does some verification on the email provided by the user

```
async function checkEmail(email) {
  const url = `https://endpoint-to-url/${email}`;
  await fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(async json => {
      let result;
      if (json.status === 200 && json.temporary === true) {
        result = true;
      } else {
        result = false;
      }
      return result;
    })
    .catch(async function(error) {
      console.log(`Error whilst checking email ${error}`);
    });
}
```

**Passport JS**

```
passport.use(
'local-signup',
new LocalStrategy(
  {
    usernameField: 'signup_email',
    passwordField: 'signup_password',
    passReqToCallback: true,
  },
  async (req, email, password, done) => {
    process.nextTick(async () => {
      const isTempEmail = await checkEmail(req.body.signup_email);
      if (isTempEmail === true) {
        return done(null, false, { errors: 'Unable to use this email' });
      }
    });
   }
  )
);
```

Each time `isTempEmail` returns `undefined`, though if I log out what is returned at the end of `checkEmail(email)` is either `true` or `false`.

I feel like I'm mixing callbacks and async/await functionality and would like to know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your `checkEmail` function doesn't return anything. Instead:

```
return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(async json => {
      let result;
      if (json.status === 200 && json.temporary === true) {
        result = true;
      } else {
        result = false;
      }
      return result;
    })
    .catch(async function(error) {
      console.log(`Error whilst checking email ${error}`);
    });
```

This is because you want to return the result of the response to the caller. You don't need to `return await` since that's redundant—`async` functions will always return a promise. If the return value is not a promise (e.g. you `return await fetch(url)`), it is wrapped in a promise. before returning to the caller. So `return fetch(url)` is sufficient.

You can even simplify this further by converting your `.then` calls into `await`s and write it as if it were synchronous.